# MenuItem hidden in fragment not visible when doing setVisible(true) in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I have been stuck on this issue for quite a while now. In my code I have a fragment inside which I do not want to show the search menu item. To achieve that I do this inside the fragment

Inside `onCreate`

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Then

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        search.setVisible(false);
    }
```

This works exactly as expected and hides the item. Now when i do back press the o`nBackPressed()` of the main activity is called and there I do this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // code skipped
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

This calls the `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside the main activity which is as follows

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        item.setVisible(true);

       //code skipped
}
```

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` function is called but unfortunately the `menuItem` still remains hidden, and I can't see the search menu.

Can someone please help, what might be the issue? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onCreateOptionsMenu` is only called when the activity is created (or the fragment). Use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to set the visibility of the menu item. The `invalidateOptionsMenu` calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, not `onCreateOptionsMenu`.